# In Google Sheets, how can I get todays date and the previous 19 days in a list. Excluding Weekends and even Holidays if possible?

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language

I start with =today() in the first cell which works fine. And then use =A2-IF(WEEKDAY(A2)<5,3,1) which I found on the internet but is giving me wrong dates.

Comment: depends... you want the output to be 19 dates or less (from 19 date window only valid dates) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getting 19 days:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SEQUENCE(19, 1, TODAY()-18), "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]

excluding weekends from those 19 days:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(19, 1, TODAY()-18), {"dd/mm/yyyy", "ddd"}), 
 "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun'"),, 1)
```

[image]

adding a list of holidays which should be excluded too:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(19, 1, TODAY()-18), {"dd/mm/yyyy", "ddd"}), 
 "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun'
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D)&"'"),, 1)
```

[image]

getting 19 entries after excluding weekends and holidays:

```
=INDEX(SORT(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(50, 1, TODAY()-49), 
 {"dd/mm/yyyy", "ddd", "@"}), 
 "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun'
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D)&"'
  order by Col3 desc 
  limit 19"), 3, 1),, 1)
```

[image]

if you for some reason need **valid** dates use:

```
=INDEX(TO_DATE(1*SORT(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE(50, 1, TODAY()-49), 
 {"dd/mm/yyy", "ddd", "@"}), 
 "where not Col2 matches 'Sat|Sun'
    and not Col1 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D2:D)&"'
  order by Col3 desc 
  limit 19"), 3, 1)),, 1)
```

[image]